# Opacity in google map cluster images

Tags: javascript, css, maps

I have this google map with some markers clusters that group/ungroup markers on zoom. **I would like to set the transparency to 25% in these cluster images** in a way I can see the city names. I´ve checked the documentation and I could not see noting related with the opacity or transparency.
Here is what I have:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {
            imagePath: 'ResourcePackages/images/spiderm'
        }
    );

    markerCluster.setStyles(markerCluster.getStyles().map(function (style) {
        style.textColor = '#fff';        
        return style;
    }));

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: CSS has an opacity? also colour can be `rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)` or `#rrggbbaa` - opacity and alpha being 0 to 1, and aa being 00 to ff for 256 shades of opacity

Comment: I thought using the api but css can also be a solution. Is it possible to select them all by the background image?

Comment: anything is possible with the right CSS selector